# Using codeship for Deploy nodejs project in the heroku, got a compiling error

Tags: node.js, heroku, github

I'm using `codeship` for deploy a `github nodejs` project in `heroku`, but got a `complied` problem in codeship,*ps:this project is running in my own dev environment well*.

## failing command:

git push heroku_ttnchat $COMMIT_ID:refs/heads/master

## log as flows:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'heroku.com,50.19.85.132' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 701, done.
Delta compression using up to 32 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (561/561), done.
Writing objects: 100% (701/701), 3.69 MiB | 4.64 MiB/s, done.
Total 701 (delta 57), reused 701 (delta 57)
-----> Node.js app detected
       PRO TIP: Specify a node version in package.json
       See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support
-----> Defaulting to latest stable node: 0.10.26
-----> Downloading and installing node
-----> Found existing node_modules directory; skipping cache
-----> Rebuilding any native dependencies
       npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs'
       npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
       npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
       npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
       
       npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
       npm ERR! command "/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/vendor/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
       npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477
       npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
       npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
       npm ERR! path /tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs
       npm ERR! code ENOENT
       npm ERR! errno 34
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/npm-debug.log
       npm ERR! not ok code 0
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/vendor/node/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/vendor/node/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'rebuild' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.3
3 info using node@v0.10.26
4 info readInstalled object
5 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477',
5 verbose rebuild   'application-name@0.0.1' ]
6 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io',
6 verbose rebuild   'socket.io@0.9.16' ]
7 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client',
7 verbose rebuild   'socket.io-client@0.9.16' ]
8 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js',
8 verbose rebuild   'uglify-js@1.2.5' ]
9 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws',
9 verbose rebuild   'ws@0.4.31' ]
10 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/commander',
10 verbose rebuild   'commander@0.6.1' ]
11 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/nan',
11 verbose rebuild   'nan@0.3.2' ]
12 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/tinycolor',
12 verbose rebuild   'tinycolor@0.0.1' ]
13 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/options',
13 verbose rebuild   'options@0.0.5' ]
14 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/xmlhttprequest',
14 verbose rebuild   'xmlhttprequest@1.4.2' ]
15 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/active-x-obfuscator',
15 verbose rebuild   'active-x-obfuscator@0.0.1' ]
16 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/active-x-obfuscator/node_modules/zeparser',
16 verbose rebuild   'zeparser@0.0.5' ]
17 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/policyfile',
17 verbose rebuild   'policyfile@0.0.4' ]
18 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/base64id',
18 verbose rebuild   'base64id@0.1.0' ]
19 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis',
19 verbose rebuild   'redis@0.7.3' ]
20 silly rebuild set [ '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io',
20 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client',
20 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js',
20 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws',
20 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/commander',
20 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/nan',
20 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/tinycolor',
20 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/options',
20 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/xmlhttprequest',
20 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/active-x-obfuscator',
20 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/active-x-obfuscator/node_modules/zeparser',
20 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/policyfile',
20 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/base64id',
20 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis' ]
21 info build /tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io
22 info preinstall socket.io@0.9.16
23 verbose linkStuff [ false,
23 verbose linkStuff   false,
23 verbose linkStuff   false,
23 verbose linkStuff   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules' ]
24 info linkStuff socket.io@0.9.16
25 verbose linkBins socket.io@0.9.16
26 verbose linkMans socket.io@0.9.16
27 verbose rebuildBundles socket.io@0.9.16
28 verbose rebuildBundles [ 'base64id', 'policyfile', 'redis', 'socket.io-client' ]
29 info install socket.io@0.9.16
30 info postinstall socket.io@0.9.16
31 info build /tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client
32 info preinstall socket.io-client@0.9.16
33 verbose linkStuff [ false,
33 verbose linkStuff   false,
33 verbose linkStuff   false,
33 verbose linkStuff   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules' ]
34 info linkStuff socket.io-client@0.9.16
35 verbose linkBins socket.io-client@0.9.16
36 verbose linkMans socket.io-client@0.9.16
37 verbose rebuildBundles socket.io-client@0.9.16
38 verbose rebuildBundles [ '.bin',
38 verbose rebuildBundles   'active-x-obfuscator',
38 verbose rebuildBundles   'uglify-js',
38 verbose rebuildBundles   'ws',
38 verbose rebuildBundles   'xmlhttprequest' ]
39 info install socket.io-client@0.9.16
40 info postinstall socket.io-client@0.9.16
41 info build /tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js
42 info preinstall uglify-js@1.2.5
43 verbose linkStuff [ false,
43 verbose linkStuff   false,
43 verbose linkStuff   false,
43 verbose linkStuff   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules' ]
44 info linkStuff uglify-js@1.2.5
45 verbose linkBins uglify-js@1.2.5
46 verbose link bins [ { uglifyjs: './bin/uglifyjs' },
46 verbose link bins   '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/.bin',
46 verbose link bins   false ]
47 verbose linkMans uglify-js@1.2.5
48 verbose rebuildBundles uglify-js@1.2.5
49 error Error: ENOENT, chmod '/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs'
50 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
50 error including the npm and node versions, at:
50 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
51 error System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
52 error command "/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/vendor/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
53 error cwd /tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477
54 error node -v v0.10.26
55 error npm -v 1.4.3
56 error path /tmp/build_0dfc619d-7fbb-4c8e-9ecd-314b01fbd477/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs
57 error code ENOENT
58 error errno 34
59 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
To git@heroku.com:ttnchat.git
 ! [remote rejected] cb14bfa35d2be4827e724c3c87e5fc2f45ac5c19 -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:ttnchat.git'
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.5.1",
    "socket.io":"0.9.16"
  }
}
```

thnks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the founders of Codeship. Have you sent a support request into Codeship so we could take a look internally? The problem is probably because you keep the node_modules folder inside of your repository.